# Performance of verifying the certification chain?

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, digital-signature

I am writing an application where performance is important. I am using a technology called *Named Data Networking*, and the a point to note is that each data packet contains a signature of the sender.

Now, I would like to verify the data packet that I receive from Bob. I validate the certification chain until the authority, etc. Suppose that after a while, I receive another data packet from Bob. If I have cached the previous certificate (suppose that only I have access to the cache), when I receive another packet from Bob with the same signature as the cached certificate, can I be sure that the data packet is authentic? Or should I verify the chain again (this process is a bit expensive for my application)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can make that assumption, at least for some time. Best would be to re-validate the signature every some many seconds/minutes/bytes depending on the use case.

If possible, try to create a packet chain. For example; every individual packet calculates an hash (take **HMAC(K,m)**) over the data **m** in the packet using key **K** which can be the the hash from the previous packet. This essentially links a chain of packets were a packet can only be valid if the previous packet was too. As an additional benefit, it does not only guarantee the authenticity but also the integrity of the data. Such a construction is *way* faster, but is not always possible. If packets are received in parallel or in random order this won't fly.